# How to make div change to fixed position when all content is visible in browser window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Not sure if the title made sense, but I noticed in the wordpress 3.8.1 admin panel, If you resize your window to where the sidebar has menu items blocked from view, it is normal positioning, which allows the sidebar to scroll.

If all the items are visible, then the sidebar has fixed positioning so that only the content to the right of the sidebar will scroll.

Neat little effect.

I was thinking it requires jQuery to add a class or change css. Maybe if the last item in the sidebar is visible then add the class, else leave it alone.

Not sure how to actually code that though.

Can someone help out, maybe even a basic fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple CSS.

```
.div_name {
position:fixed;
}
```

check [W3schools Position fixed property for tags](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed)

Comment: Not quite. If its always position fixed then it will never be able to scroll when needed. Thanks though

Comment: .div_name {
position:fixed;
overflow:auto;
}

this will make it scrollable too...